# How to grab the relative positions of a signiture in canvas on top of text

Tags: javascript, sql-server, html, canvas, svg

I have a contract text which is stored into MS SQL VARMAX field. When loaded into a canvas I need to have the user signed in different places. Then need to save the signatures as svg format. But how do I grab the relative positions of each signature? So when I load back the text I can show the signatures in the right positions.

Thanks,

Doron

Comment: add some code and tell us what have you tried.

Comment: How is the signature itself bounded? If you can isolate the signature with some surrounding white space, then you can use context.getImageData to analyze those pixels and isolate the signature itself. Turning those raster pixels into a svg paths is quite more complicated however.

Comment: I was converting the text to an image using ImageMagick. Then combined the signature with the text image to one image and store that in the HD. That was a year and half ago. 

Now with HTML5 canvas, I realized that it can be done differently on the fly while grabbing the text from the database and the image definition for the signature and then combine them together as one file on the fly. I stored the signature as base 64 in the database. But I can change that as SVG format. 

I need some start up code to get me going…
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the below code and that is a great start up.<s> 

I did not mention that in addition to the signature there could be 2 initials some where on the contract (Not all the time). Say for Joe Doe as jd in 2 places (Hand written).  How would you hand that?

Comment: I've added to my answer regarding how to capture multiple signatures and/or initials on the canvas. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When the person initially signs the contract, presumably you will have a separate canvas positioned directly over your contract text. The signatory will move the mouse/pen over the canvas to create their signature. The signature will be the only opaque pixels on the canvas.

You can use `getImageData` to fetch the pixel data for the canvas. Then you can loop through each pixel and save the leftmost, topmost, rightmost and bottommost opaque pixel position. That gives your desired bounding box for the signature.

Here's how to get the bounding box of a signature on the canvas.

```
function findBoundary(){
    var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch).data;
    var top=1000000;
    var left=1000000;
    var right=-10;
    var bottom=-10;
    for(var y=0;y<ch;y++){
    for(var x=0;x<cw;x++){
        var n=(y*cw+x)*4+3;
        if(data[n]>200){
            if(x<left){left=x;}
            if(x>right){right=x;}
            if(y<top){top=y;}
            if(y>bottom){bottom=y;}
        }
    }}
    return({x:left,y:top,width:right-left+1,height:bottom-top+1});
}
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

Note: This simple demo isn't meant to be a signature capture app--I assume you already have a full signature app. It just draws a stoke as you drag the mouse and shows you the bounding box of the stroke when you release the mouse.

[image]

```js
var $results=$('#results');

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.lineWidth=2;

var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

var isDown=false;
var startX;
var startY;

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});


function findBoundary(){
  var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch).data;
  var top=1000000;
  var left=1000000;
  var right=-10;
  var bottom=-10;
  for(var y=0;y<ch;y++){
    for(var x=0;x<cw;x++){
      var n=(y*cw+x)*4+3;
      if(data[n]>200){
        if(x<left){left=x;}
        if(x>right){right=x;}
        if(y<top){top=y;}
        if(y>bottom){bottom=y;}
      }
    }}
  return({x:left,y:top,width:right-left+1,height:bottom-top+1});
}



function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.lineWidth=3;
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  isDown=true;
}

function handleMouseUpOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  isDown=false;

  var pos=findBoundary();
  ctx.strokeStyle='red';
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.globalAlpha=0.50;
  ctx.strokeRect(pos.x,pos.y,pos.width,pos.height);
  ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;

  $results.text(
    'Signature boundary x/y: '
    +parseInt(pos.x)+'/'
    +parseInt(pos.y)+', width/height: '
    +parseInt(pos.width)+'/'
    +parseInt(pos.height)
  );
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mouseOut stuff here
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousemove stuff here
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX,startY);
  ctx.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
  ctx.stroke();
  startX=mouseX;
  startY=mouseY;

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id='results'>Sign by dragging</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**[ Addition based on additional question ]**

> In addition to the signature there could be 2 initials some where on
>   the contract...How would you hand that?

**That involves set recognition through establishing a bounding box.**

1. Find the row containing the topmost opaque pixel,
2. Move downward by row until you have sufficient rows with no opaque pixels (== until you're sure the signature is vertically complete).
3. Find the column containing the leftmost opaque pixel,
4. Move rightward by column until you have sufficient rows with no opaque pixels (== until you're sure the signature is horizontally complete).
5. The bounding box of the signature is the left/right and top/bottom pixels determined in #1-4.
6. Erase the pixels in the bounding box.

At this point you've successfully captured the first signature (or initials).

Repeat steps #1-6 until you find no pixels (== until there are no more signatures or initials).

Good luck with your project!